# Why doesn't `text.charAt(i+1) <= text.length()` work?

Tags: java, if-statement

```
case 1: 
if (text1Input.charAt(i+1) <= text1Input.length() &&
    Character.isUpperCase(text1Input.charAt(i+1)))
{
  a += 60;
  b += 100;
}
else
{
  a += 55;
  b += 60;
}
break;
```

Does this line of code make sense? It doesn't work how I want it to and can't figure out the problem.
The code is meant to check the next character in a string. If the character exists (meaning hasn't reached the end of the string already), and the character is uppercase, it uses these coordinates. Else, it uses the others. My problem is that it always uses the latter regardless of case.

Answer (score 7):

Youre comparing a character to a location, which might not be what you intended, so you might use `i+1` instead of `x.charAt(i+1)`

Answer (score 4):

The line

```
text1Input.charAt(i+1) <= text1Input.length()
```

does not make sense.  What would make more sense is

```
i+1 < text1Input.length()
```

What you're doing now compares the ASCII value of the `i+1`th character of `text1Input` to its length, which is nonsensical.  (You should also be using `i+1 < text1Input.length()`, as opposed to `<=`.)